# How to fix append function

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I'm very new to Python and I think the problem in my code is that my append function isn't working properly. What I'm trying to do is get my code to go line by line through a file and print as many location names as possible. As far as I can tell it is going through line by line but my output is nothing but empty brackets. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```py
for item in entry:
    if (identifying_keywords in entry):
        location_holder = entry[(entry.find("identifying_keywords")+6):]
        location_list.append(location_holder)
        
print(location_list)
```

Comment: maybe u should try `if identifying_keywords in item`. btw u need to clarify it more.

Comment: The problem is that `identifying_keywords` is in speech marks but it shouldn't be

Comment: There's not nearly enough detail for us to offer any meaningful advice. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input, expected output, and enough code that we can reproduce the error or wrong output. What is `entry[(entry.find("identifying_keywords")+6):]` doing? Have you checked that it's outputting what you expect?

Comment: Why doesn't the loop use the `item` variable? You're doing the same thing every time through the loop.